# How to remove border around anchor tag button image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, anchor

How can i remove the border of the button.

CSS

```
#button-test{
  background-image: url('images/icon.png') !important; 
  height: 70px !important; 
  width: 49px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  border:none;
  border-radius:0px;
  border-style:none;

  border-width:0px;
  outline:0;
  background:none;

  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow:none;
}
```

And HTML

```
<a id="button-test" data-role="button" ></a>
```

The image with the visible border is as follows[image]

In the css file i already tried most of the properties as you can see.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a fiddle? It seems the border your are highlighting is part of the image itself.

Comment: you sure that this border is not coming from image...looks like lack of image-finishing to me!!

Comment: What about border radius?

Comment: could you try `display:block`

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use anchor as button and to remove border and outline type `border: none; outline: none;`

Comment: Border-radius cannot remove your border perfectly. For this only photoshop =P

Comment: I already checked, its not the image border. the border appears even if i remove the image itself from the button